# Spreadsheet javascript function does not return anything

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My function cell is showing `Error`.
I simply couldn't figure out why my spreadsheet script doesn't return anything.
I traced the whole function but still can't find why I not getting any values back. Spreadsheet scripting and Javascript are pretty new to me and I'm kind of stuck here.

```
 // Range is a 2D array with one row and 5 columns
 // for example [[2,4,6,7,8]]
 // stock is a value of a single cell
 function StockCoverW(stock, range) {
     var x = stock;
     var v = 0;
     var stock1;
     var c = range[0].length;
     var i = 0;
     while (i < c) {

         x = x - v;
         v = range[0][i];

         if (x == v) {
             stock1 = i;
         } else if (x < v) {
             var p = i;
             var z = x / v;
             stock1 = p + z;
         } else {
             i = i + 1;
         }
     }
     return stock1;
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't return anything because it doesn't have a return statement

Comment: @L_Church erm scroll down a bit. there is a return statement :3

Comment: oh i see tiny little scroll uh maybe its null have you done any debugging on it

Comment: It does have a return statement. The problem is that you hit an endless loop, and the function never finishes. This happens because you increment "i" inside the conditional statement, so as soon as one of the other conditions is met (x == v or x < v), the variable "i" will stop incrementing, so (i < c) expression will always be true;

Comment: @AntonDementiev You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @AntonDementiev Thanks a lot buddy. Got it right.